# Подсветка синтаксиса для ahk в sublime text 3

Tags: синтаксис, sublime-text-3, autohotkey

Помогите сделать подсветку синтаксиса ahk(Auto Hot Key) в sublime text 3. Спасибо

Comment: Не уверен, но попробуйте указать в настройках подсветку синтаксиса для языка JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить Packages/SublimeAutoHotkey-master/AutoHotkey.tmLanguage [тут](https://github.com/ahkscript/SublimeAutoHotkey):
Если нужно, чтобы подсветка синтаксиса AHK была по-умолчанию, то этот скрипт:

```py
       import sublime, sublime_plugin
       class DefaultSyntaxCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
       def on_new(self, view):
       view.set_syntax_file('Packages/SublimeAutoHotkey- 
       master/AutoHotkey.tmLanguage')
```

нужно положить в папку User, с расширением py в AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User.